# How to count bounce back email using php script

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I am searching for the steps to write the PHP script to count the bounce back email of the particular date.

Can anybody tell me the right way to get the **bounce back email count** by using PHP script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't your personal army of coders. If you need something created, then rent a coder. HOWEVER, if you're willing to show the code you've got so far, then we'll be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this class before:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2691-PHP-Parse-bounced-e-mail-message-reports.html

Think this is where you're looking for, take a look at their script. I've learned many things out of this class myself!